# Set gradient color for text in Android Studio with Kotlin language

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, kotlin, gradient

I have a text and I want to set a gradient color as its foreground. May I do it in XML?

Or should I do it in an activity? I am programming with Kotlin in Android Studio.

#### File activity_main.xml

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Text Color is Gradient"
        android:textColor="#000"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

#### File gradient.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
    <gradient
        android:angle="90"
        android:centerColor="#555994"
        android:endColor="#b5b6d2"
        android:startColor="#555994"
        android:type="linear" />

    <corners
        android:radius="0dp"/>

</shape>
```

My activity is this:

```
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    }
}
```

Comment: inside xml, set background to the textview.. replace android:background="#FFFFFF" to android:background="@drawable/gradient"

Comment: It doesn't work @Raza, does it work for you?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In order to set the gradient as `Textview` text color, you have to use `textshader` with parsing gradients color. You can customise the colors as of your requirement.

```
 val paint = textView.paint
        val width = paint.measureText(textView.text.toString())
        val textShader: Shader = LinearGradient(0f, 0f, width, textView.textSize, intArrayOf(
            Color.parseColor("#F97C3C"),
            Color.parseColor("#FDB54E"),
            /*Color.parseColor("#64B678"),
            Color.parseColor("#478AEA"),*/
            Color.parseColor("#8446CC")
        ), null, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT)

        textView.paint.setShader(textShader)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Raza, but this code will make background of my textview gradient while I want my text to be gradient. In other words, now my text is black, I want to make it gradient.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209700/discussion-between-mohammadmoeingolchin-and-raza).

Comment: Hi Raza, see my bounty question. Had you this problem when you used alertdialog? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60462748/

Comment: don't you know answer of this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60582383/bottomnavigationviews-titles-color-being-a-gradient

Answer (score 1):

try like this in kotlin

```
binding.textView.setTextColor(resources.getColor(R.color.snooze_gradient_start))

        val textShader: Shader = LinearGradient(
            0f, binding.textView.paint.measureText(binding.textView.text.toString()), 0f, 0f, intArrayOf(
                resources.getColor(R.color.gradient_start), resources.getColor(R.color.gradient_end)
            ), floatArrayOf(0f, 1f), Shader.TileMode.CLAMP
        )
    binding.textView.paint.shader = textShader
```