# multiple textview in layout to follow a gradient color [Android]

Tags: android, textview, gradient, typography

I am trying to set a gradient color to multiple textviews in a linearlayout, the start and end color the gradient, should start from the top to bottom of the layout

[image: I would like to achieve this as gradient color]
[image: I would like to achieve this as gradient color]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60631322/set-gradient-color-for-text-in-android-studio-with-kotlin-language

Comment: @MohammadMoeinGolchin the given Url is for gradient for single textview, Im trying to achieve a gradient for multiple textview, without repeating the gradient color

Comment: OK, use that question and answer for each textview separately